# Cannot install package on Laravel v6.1

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Im trying to install yajra datatable to my project using

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0
```

But its returning the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 9.0 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v9.0.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.1.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.1.0
- yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.0.0 requires illuminate/view 5.8.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.8.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
```

**System details:**

```
Windows 10

Php v7.2.5

Laravel v6.1

Laravel-Datatables v9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error above:

> yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.0.0 requires illuminate/view 5.8.*
>   -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.8.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17,  v5.8.18, v5.8.19,  v5.8.2,  v5.8.20,  v5.8.22,
>   v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30,  v5.8.31,  v5.8.32,
>   v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].

Seems like `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.0.0` doesn't support Laravel `6`, it only goes up to Laravel `5.8.*` .

So one solution could be to downgrade your Laravel version to `5.8.*`. To do that, inside your composer.json, change `laravel/framework` to following:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
```

Then do `composer update`, and try to install the package again. Don't forget to clear and config the application cache, before composer update:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Change composer.json

```
"laravel/framework": "6.1",
```

to

```
"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
```

then

```
composer install
```

and retry

Comment: Its now saying ```Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v6.1.0, required as ^5.8) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.```

Comment: let me see your composer.json pls

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem. I used the Laravel documentation from Laravel site and in top right corner of the site selected correct version of my Laravel framework to see true documentation for this version. I hope this works for you too.